# Are Some Polynomial regression matrices Symmetric Positive Definite

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Suppose say I want a quadratic regression to map my data, this will generate a 3x3 matrix such as:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^0  &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^1 &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^2 \\
    \sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^1  &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^2 &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^3 \\
    \sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^2  &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^3 &\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^{0}y_i \\
\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^{1}y_i \\
\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i x_i^{2}y_i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I wish to know whether `A` is an SPD matrix for such a case or for any polynomial regression matrix. It can be seen that `A` is symmetric, but I'm not sure how to proceed for testing whether `A` is positive definite. I have tried to go with the eigenvalue approach, but I failed..

Could this be proven?

As a little side note, this information of `A` being an SPD allows me to shortcut LU decomposition algorithm to solve this system of equations.

As an added assumption for my specific use case, consider that all $x,y \in \Bbb R^+$. I'm not sure whether this assumption helps in proving/disproving SPD case.

Comment: It is not SPD in general. Say if you set $w_i = x_i =1$. For a given one you can verify through the eigenvalues, why would you fail with it?

Comment: wow, totally missed that! But what if we are given the matrix is linear independent? Because, x is my explanatory variable, it won't stay constant. the same applies to w. I'm sorry for not clarifying this in the question.